# Is there something wrong with BitArrays in C#?

Tags: c#, xor, bitarray

When I conpile this code:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(3);
bits[0] = true;
bits[1] = true; 
bits[2] = true;

BitArray moreBits = new BitArray(3);
bits[0] = true;
bits[1] = true;
bits[2] = true;

BitArray xorBits = bits.Xor(moreBits);

foreach (bool bit in xorBits)
{
Console.WriteLine(bit);
}
```

I get the following output:

> > True  True  True

When I do an xor on two boolean values by saying true ^ true i get false.

Is there something wrong with the code. My memory of the truth table for XOR was that True XOR True is false.

Comment: Frameworks like C#'s or Java's are almost never at fault because so many other people are using them and testing them. Always check your own code first. In this case Kent's answer covers it.

Comment: yeah I tried to delete the question once I'd noticed that but because his answer has been voted up I can't delete it. Somone else close it.

Comment: Why is this getting up voted?

Comment: you can close your own question

Comment: No you can votw to close it, but not close it... I need 3 more votes. and it's been upvoted again... I despair... do people actually read questions? At least Kent got a good answer badge for spotting my idiocy...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Copy and paste error.

```
BitArray moreBits = new BitArray(3);
bits[0] = true;
bits[1] = true;
bits[2] = true;
```

That should be:

```
BitArray moreBits = new BitArray(3);
moreBits[0] = true;
moreBits[1] = true;
moreBits[2] = true;
```

Comment: Been there, done that. And it's not an error you make once, early in your career, and never repeat - copy/paste gremlins lurk forever behind your monitor, just waiting for a momentary lapse in concentration. ;)

Answer (score 5):

You are setting `bits` to `true` twice. You are not settings `moreBits` to `true`, so it defaults to all-`false`. I blame copy/paste!

EDIT: in the short time it took me to write this Kent answered and got upvoted 8 times!